# PCSCConnector and Windows 7

Tags: delphi, windows-7, smartcard, pcsc

I'm using `PCSCConnector` from http://nobbi.com, last update - April 2004.
All work fine with Windows XP but with Windows 7 there has been some trouble.

When I press CTRL+F2 in the Delphi IDE (terminate) and a card connection had been opened by my software then any software (including my own) can't open a new connection to the card. I need to physically reconnect the card (USB in my case) to be able to create new connections to it.

I try to change `dwScope` in `SCardEstablishContext` to `SCARD_SCOPE_SYSTEM` (from `SCARD_SCOPE_USER`) and `dwDisposition` in `SCardDisconnect` to `SCARD_LEAVE_CARD` (from `SCARD_RESET_CARD`) but the problem persists.

Comment: Is your user going to be doing this? I use PCSCConnector (though it's been refined over the years. Hint: try to get it more in line with the actual specs), and I don't have any issues where the card gets locked. You don't seem to have a standard smartcard if it's integrated via USB. I think normally you have a reader and a card, and connections are made to both.

Answer (score 2):

When you use <kbd>Ctrl+F2</kbd>, it's a forceful termination. No code gets a chance to properly clean up, close things, or free anything - it's just shut down. No changes you make to the library's exit code is going to help, because it never gets a chance to run. You've stopped that from happening by forcefully terminating the app.

The solution: Don't use <kbd>Ctrl+F2</kbd> for anything except runaway code you can't stop any other way. Close down your application normally the way it's supposed to be closed down, so it has a chance to clean things up and call `finalization` code and so forth.

Comment: Yes, but smart cards can be connected using an exclusive connection or not. `SCARD_SCOPE_USER` may not require an exclusive connection. Of course, a good OS should make the smart card available again. But either the OS is buggy in this regard, or the context has not been lost and the exclusive connection persists.

Comment: Finalization don't solve and in Windows XP Ctrl+F2 normally perceived.

Comment: I specifically said "Finalization doesn't work if you force your app to close improperly". Please read what I wrote again. If you use Ctrl+F2, things **do not get a chance to properly shut down**. If you want it to close properly, **do not use Ctrl+F2 to close it**.

Comment: I'm sorry, but releasing resources when an application has been terminated is not rocket science. Furthermore, you are talking like "forceful termination" is the end of the discussion, while it wasn't on XP. I'm not sure just focussing on that term is enough of an answer for me, I would surely like to know what is causing this. That said, the smart card handling of Windows changes each iteration and this issue is pretty localized, so we may never know.

Comment: Ctrl+F2 **is** a forceful termination, regardless of how you choose to think about it. What is causing this is **improper termination of your application**. I'm not sure what other words to use to say it. **If you want neat closure, close it neatly**. If you choose to hit it with a hammer, don't be surprised if it breaks. If you decide that you want to stop your car is to steer it into a tree rather than use the brakes as it's designed to be stopped, you should expect some unexpected things to happen. I'm not sure ignoring the answer is going to help you, but I give up. :-) Good luck.